# Browser error after publishing web site to AZURE

Tags: .net, azure, razor, web-applications

I published a test version of my .net core 2.2 Razor Web App to Azure. After 2-3 hours of working, I get the following error: Any ideas how to solve?

> ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID You cannot visit (my site name here)
>   right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks
>   are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

Comment: seems to be an SSL problem. Try to generate your certificate using https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Navigate to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`,onfirm the domain’s HSTS settings are recorded by Chrome, type the hostname into the **Query Domain** section. Type the same hostname into the **Delete domain** section and click.

Comment: I tried deleting the hostname, but no result, still the same problem persists. This is very strange. Now the whole site is blocked for phishing. It is an asp.net core 2.2 razor pages application.sharelockmanager.azurewebsites.net